# User suddenly don't see correct DFS share on some servers

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, dfs

Setup: 2 Windows 2008 R2 DC also holding DFS shares, replication works fine.

Suddenly my user (is administrator too) got the wrong/empty redirected desktop etc. I only see the local C:\users\public desktop / default profile.
If I create a new folder it seems to be saved on the DFS path, but it must be some kind of a "local cache" because it's otherwise empty. So it doesn't seems to be a temp profile as the desktop path is correct.
From other servers I can see files on that path and my desktop etc is correct.

I can access my files directly on both DCs via \server-ip\dfs\

/Kim

Comment: Sounds like one of your replicas is out of sync or otherwise not working.  Try accessing the share from different replicas to see where the issue lies, and then run your various DFS diagnostics to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Okay, found out some more:
My desktop is redirected to \\domain.local\dfs$\usr\UserName\Desktop when I save to this folder it's saved on the DFS servers on: E:\DFSRoots\dfs$\usr\UserName\Desktop, but the real path, which is working from other servers is: E:\DFSRoots\dfs-data\usr\UserName\Desktop (all my files are still there)

Comment: ...alright.  There's probably/usually another server or servers that also serve up the same content, one of which is not working properly.  If you right click in a folder that's a DFS target, and select `properties`, then click on the DFS tab, you should be able to see the referral list (a list of the servers that contain the DFS path in question).  Check them all, and find out which one, or ones, is not displaying the proper content, and from there you can troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED! :)

Really strange.. I saw on one DC in DFSroots my profile was created in E:\DFSRoots\dfs$ (as stated earlier) where only links to DFS folders are stored, it should be created under \DFSRoots\dfs-data\usr.

I had two namespaces \usr and \usr$, usr$ was only for testing, but it was on that target folder the profile was created. So renamed it, and deleted E:\DFSRoots\dfs$\usr after a restart of DFS Namespace the reparse point was recreated. And it worked again,

I ran DFSDIAG /TestDFSIntegrity which pointed me to this, I've got this waring:

> The reparse point for the following DFS folder (link) does not exist

Very strange this just happen out of the blue, the DFS setup have not been changed for a year or two.